# Function to obtain the id on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got myself all in a mess. When each of the "..." within the span is clicked, I would like the myDropdown div containing "Report" to be shown next to the span. 
Then I would like for when the corresponding Report is clicked to return the id of the "elementid" class in this case either 1 or 2 but I wasn't sure what to put in the reportFunction

```
<html>
<style>
.dropbtn {
background-color: white;
color: black;
padding: 2px;
font-size: 30px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
font-weight: bold;
}

.dropdown {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
font-size:10px;
overflow: auto;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
border: 1px solid lightgrey;
z-index: 1;
float: left;
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1;cursor:pointer;}

.show {display:block;}
</style>

<span class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">...</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
<a class="elementid" id="1">Report</a>
</div>
</span>
<p>    
<span class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">...</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
<a class="elementid" id="2">Report</a>
</div>
</span>

<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
var i;
var id = document.getElementsByID("id");
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
  }
}
}
}

function reportFunction() {

}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: `.classList` is not widely supported, at least not with `.toggle()`. Also, span's are inline Elements, meaning they don't take a height and don't cause a line break. If you truly want style, I recommend using a block level Element, like a `<div>` with floating or absolute position. Just a comment.

Comment: Just more comments here. Inline Elements should only have other inline Elements within them, unless you change the CSS display property. You should attach the click Event directly to the Element, not to the window, then it won't fire when whenever the window is clicked.

Comment: @PHPglue thanks and any ideas how to achieve what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you the id you want. It goes up to the containing span with `parent()` and then gets the element with class `elementId` within.

```
function reportFunction() {
    var id = $(this).parent().find('.elementid');
    ... //whatever you need to do
}
```

Your code has other problems though. You have two `div` elements with the same id `myDropdown`. Your current code with `getElementById` will always get the first one. You need to either specify a class and no id on them, and get the right one in the same way as above, or to use one `div` that you remove and attach to the correct span as needed.